# Resizing an lvm2 pv CentOS partition

Tags: centos, partition, virtualbox

I have installed CentOS on Windows VirtualBox host. I had initially allocated 50GB but I ran out of space so I extended the vdi to 100 GB and then used a GParted live CD to extend the lmv2 pv partition from 50 GB to 100 GB. When rebooting to CentOS it remained 50 GB. So I reshrinked the partition. Anyway it looks like this after reverting the change.

[image]

Since after the initial extension of the partition the vdi on the VirtualBox settings was still looking like 50 GB as depicted here

[image]

I really don't know whether this is a Linux or VirtualBox question. Any insights?

Comment: You need to run `pvresize /dev/sda2` after resizing the partition it's on. But take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365775/why-resize-a-pv-instead-of-adding-a-new-pv/365791#365791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the additional space, you need to resize 5 things:

1. The disk (VDI)
2. The partition
3. The physical volume
4. The logical volume
5. The filesystem

What you can to is...

1. Resize the VDI and partition, like you did before.
2. Resize the physical volume with the command: `pvresize /dev/sda2`
3. Resize the logical volume and filesystem in one go with the command: `lvresize -L +50G /dev/YOUR_VOLUME_GROUP_NAME/vg_centos6`