# How to extend lv without loss of data on other lvs within partition

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

I want to extend my logical volume mounted to /home:

```
lsblk
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                       11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
xvda                     202:0    0  125G  0 disk
├─xvda1                  202:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─xvda2                  202:2    0 74.5G  0 part
  ├─centos_jenslv05-root 253:0    0   48G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos_jenslv05-swap 253:1    0    3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos_jenslv05-home 253:2    0 23.5G  0 lvm  /home
```

As you can see xvda has 125GB and xvda1 + xvda2 have only 75GB combined. The extra 50GB is what i want to add to centos_jenslv05-home logical volume.

PVS

```
pvs
  PV         VG              Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/xvda2 centos_jenslv05 lvm2 a--  74.51g    0
```

VGS

```
vgs
  VG              #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  centos_jenslv05   1   3   0 wz--n- 74.51g    0
```

LVS

```
lvs
  LV   VG              Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home centos_jenslv05 -wi-ao---- 23.45g
  root centos_jenslv05 -wi-ao---- 48.04g
  swap centos_jenslv05 -wi-ao----  3.02g
```

So basically i need to extend the partition dev/xvda2, add it to the PV, add it to VG and then to LVM which is mounted to home.

However, i don't want to loose data on root lv (/), which is on the same partition as the home lv (/home). Is there a way to extend only one logical volume, without touching other lvs? If it's not possible and i need to delete the partition and then recreate it with added space, will backing up all the files on /root and /home be enough? Can i recreate parition, then recreate lvs and copy the files back to lvs and will it start the server as it was? Is it safe?

I know that extending logical volume without touching others is possible on Windows, but not sure if it's as handy on Linux. The system is Centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98339/how-do-i-extend-a-partition-with-a-lvm-and-the-contained-physical-volume-and-log) explaining your 2 options.

Either

1. Extend the existing `pv` with `gparted`, resize the `vg` with `vgextend /dev/xda2` and then extend your `lv`.

Or

2. Add a new `pv` by creating a new volume (xda3) in the unused space on xda, add the new partition to the `vg` and then extend the `lv` into the new space.

in either case you will need to resize your file-system to make the capacity available but you can do this using `lvextend -r` when you resize.

Looking at your partition schema, the free space will be contiguous with xda2 and either option is viable though option 1 is the more aesthetically pleasing (see @Patrick post in the above link).

Since you are not actually touching the `root` (logical) partition then you should be able to do this from your live system. If not then you will need a live usb.