# df shows drive as 77gb but fdisks shows the partition as 160gb

Tags: hard-disk, fdisk

I recently upgraded my VPS's HDD space from 80 > 160gb, but it is not showing the changes other than when viewing it in fdisks.

```
root@localhost:~# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  794M  1.2M  793M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01   77G   31G   43G  43% /
tmpfs                  3.9G   16K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1              456M  145M  278M  35% /boot
tmpfs                  794M     0  794M   0% /run/user/0

root@localhost:~# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 160 GiB, 171798691840 bytes, 335544320 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x520f1760

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 335544286 334544863 159.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

I have tried to use resize2fs but I get:

```
root@localhost:~# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01 
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 20345856 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I've a feeling I needed to create a new partition to be able to do this?

To make matters more confusing for me vgdisplay shows that there is no free space:

```
root@localhost:~# vgdisplay vg00
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg00
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <79.52 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              20357
  Alloc PE / Size       20357 / <79.52 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               ZRC0sL-qOeU-Uyfp-Qbo4-m06c-CwEt-xpFTsO
```

Comment: You're missing the step of enlarging the LVM physical volume `/dev/sda2`, then enlarging the LVM logical volume `vg00-lv01`.

Comment: The linked answer doesn't really tell me how, does it. When I looked it just said that you can... but not with the cmds on how to.

Comment: The [most upvoted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98374) has the two commands you need (`pvresize` and `lvextend`).

Comment: Well I'll be... that was easy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend the disk for your OS, you need to do some tasks for extendig it for lvm:

1. If you don't want to reboot the system, you need to rescan disk for seek new size, e.g for /dev/sda:

   echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan

you'll see new space for disk (160G)

2. Next, you need to extend partition, which belongs pv

   parted /dev/sda 2 resizepart 100%
3. After that, resize pv:

   pvresize /dev/sda2

And just resize your lv and fs:

```
lvextend -l+100%FREE -r /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01
```

NOTE:
Flag '-r' for lvextend:

```
-r|--resizefs
         Resize underlying filesystem together with the LV using fsadm(8).
```

But you can resize underlying fs yourself, depend of your fs-type:

```
xfs: xfs_growfs /
ext: resize2fs /
```

Comment: Thanks @spybull. `parted /dev/sda 2 resizepart 100%` actually just outputs gparted help menu as its not a valid command it seems. So I tried `$ parted; $ (parted) resizepart 100%                                                  
Error: /dev/sda2: unrecognised disk label
`

Answer (score 0):

From inside your VM you have to check whether you can see the new space availlable.

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda  #or whatever your main device is
```

so you will see if you have some more space than your original 80G, sometimes you need to stop your VM and restart it, most of the time a reboot may be enough for the kernel to detect space changes, but if you can't try one of these solution:

```
sfdisk -R /dev/sda
partx -a /dev/sda
kpartx -a /dev/sda
hdparm -z /dev/sda
blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sda
partprobe  /dev/sda
```

from now you may have some free space on your device and you got two way to exploit them, (1)you can extend your original partition or (2)you can add a new one.

to extend your partition(1)

```
pvs #this will give you the used partitions here 2 for the example 
parted /dev/sda resizepart 2      159GB
       ^disk    ^cmd       ^part# ^pos.last.sector
```

last number should be the desired end position so the max size you will be able to use.

to add a second partition(2) just use `fdisk sfdisk gdisk` or like, and add a partition at the end and tag it 8e or 8E00 if using GPT partition table format. Then add this second partition to your LVM.

```
pvcreate /dev/sda3
vgextend  vg00 /dev/sda3
```

from now you may have some free space reported on your Volume group by `vgs` or  `vgdisplay`  and you can just extend your volumes.